# How to create an alert message in jsp page after submit process is complete

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to add a message in my jsp after the process is done by hitting the submit button.

```
function onSubmit() {
alert("Master_Data.xlsx and Consistency_Check_Data.xlsx are located under d:/stage/MasterDataReports");
}
</script>
<body>

<form name="input" action="getMasterData" method="get">



    <br />
    <br />
    <h1 align='center'>Master Data File</h1>
    <br />
    <br />


    <table border="0" align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Site Name</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'>
            <jsp:useBean id="masterDao" class="master.dao.MasterDataDao"/>
            <select name="siteId" id="siteId">
            <option value="0">ALL</option>
             <c:forEach items="${masterDao.allSites}" var="siteDto">
             <option value="${siteDto.id}">${siteDto.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Division</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'>
            <jsp:useBean id="masterDaoUtil" class="master.dao.util.MasterDataConstants"/>
            <select name="divisionId" id="divisionId">
            <option value="33"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_AUDIT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="31"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_CHANGE_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="34"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_DEA_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="35"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EHS_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="23"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: center">
        **strong text**<input type="submit" value="Submit" OnClick="onSubmit()">
    </div>
```

Right now the submit process will only happen after I clear the alert. Is there a way that I can either pop an alert after the submit process is done or if I can add a message to the jsp page?
Thanks in advance
Sonny

Here is my updated Servlet that is causing error:

```
package master.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
**strong text**import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class MasterDataServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    MasterDataService masterDataService = new MasterDataService();
    try {
        int siteId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("siteId"));
        int divisionId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("divisionId"));
        //For master data file
        masterDataService.createMasterDataFile(siteId, divisionId,false);
        //For consistency checker file 
        masterDataService.createMasterDataFile(siteId, divisionId,true);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/masterDataQueryScreen.jsp").forward(request, response);
        **strong text**session.setAttribute("getAlert", "Yes");//Just initialize a random variable.
        **strong text**response.sendRedirect("/masterDataQueryScreen.jsp");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So let's say after getMasterData servlet will response.sendRedirect to to test.jsp.

In test.jsp

Create a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertName(){
alert("Form has been submitted");
} 
</script>
```

and than at the bottom

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = alertName; </script>
```

Note:im not sure how to type the code in stackoverflow!. 
Edit: I just learned how to

Edit 2:
TO the question:This works perfectly. Another question. How would I get rid of the initial alert when I first start up the JSP? "Form has been submitted" is present the second I execute. It shows up after the load is done to which is perfect.

To do that i would highly recommendation to use session!

So what you want to do is in your servlet:

```
session.setAttribute("getAlert", "Yes");//Just initialize a random variable.
response.sendRedirect(test.jsp);
```

than in the test.jsp

```
<%
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(2);
%>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var Msg ='<%=session.getAttribute("getAlert")%>';
    if (Msg != "null") {
 function alertName(){
 alert("Form has been submitted");
 } 
 }
 </script>
```

and than at the bottom

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = alertName; </script>
```

So everytime you submit that form a session will be pass on! If session is not null the function will run!

Comment: This works perfectly. Another question. How would I get rid of the initial alert when I first start up the JSP? "Form has been submitted" is present the second I execute. It shows up after the load is done to which is perfect.

Comment: Sonny i've answer the question above

Comment: I have added the changes as you requested but for some reason I am getting a "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL". I have posted my Servlet page above where I boldified the changes(**strong text**). Am I missing something? And also do you need to see my jsp? Thanks

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

in your servlet

```
 request.setAttribute("submitDone","done");
 return mapping.findForward("success");
```

In your jsp

```
<c:if test="${not empty submitDone}">
  <script>alert("Form submitted");
</script></c:if>
```

Comment: in the return mapping.findForward("success"); line, what would I declare mapping as in the servlet. Do I have to create a class called mapping? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new jsp file sayng that form is submited and in your main action file just write its file name

Eg. Your form is submited is in a file succes.jsp
Then your action file will have

```
Request.sendRedirect("success.jsp")
```